# How can I use response.write() without displaying the whole page

Tags: .net

I have a normal aspx page which accept POST request and expected to send a response back the the one who made the request over http.

I used response.write(data) to send a response back to the user but, it sends the whole page back instead of just the "data"

This is the code snippet

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

  Response.Clear();
  Response.ContentType = "text/plain";

  string myparam = (string)Request.QueryString["myparam"];

  //Perform some operations then generate a response
  data="Ok"
  Response.Write(data);
  Response.End();

}// End
```

The Issue is instead of sending just the data back only i.e "Ok", it sends "OK" plus the whole DOM of the page "

Please I need help on how to do away with the rest of the string whenever anyone request for my POST page over http. I want to get ONLY "Ok" at the other end.

Comment: You are probably looking into implementing some sort of Ajax posting. Perhaps write a handler (ashx) and call it using jQuery $.ajax (for example)

Comment: You need to clear the aspx part so the code behind everything

Answer (score -1):

You can use buffering and flush.

```
Response.BufferOutput = true

// iterate through content
Response.Write(content so far)
Response.Flush()

... keep going

Response.Write(more content)
Response.Flush()
```

---

If you are looking to build a web service API and return data and not Response, you can read the following article:  http://www.iwantmymvc.com/rest-service-mvc3

View particularly the part on returning Json content:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult CommentList(List<Comment> items)
    {
        var model = this.commentManager.CreateComments(items);
        return Json(model);
    }
```

Your method is PageLoad which implies you're returning a web page, but you want to only return a string which is closer to a web service api response.  Hopefully this steers you in the right direction.

---

**Have you tried explicity setting the content type to text/plain?**

```
context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have tried that, I still have the DOM as part of the response. the issue is when i write Response.write("Ok"); it sends "Ok <!DOCTYPE html....." , I only want to see string "Ok" at the other end.

Comment: What it sounds like is you are trying to build an API and send back data on response, and not a web page response on requests which is what you are getting.  Your question didn't specify that but it would make sense with your comments.  See additional content in my answer above (edits)

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, I was trying to build an API that sends data back as response on request. I was using a normal .aspx page to achieve that and I get the response in form of a whole page, I think I will have to look in the direction of creating a web service in your comment above.

Comment: Try the ContentType setting on the response just in case, but then Web Service likely your best bet.  Also I appreciate you up-voting.

Comment: I have tried ContentType it does not work. I think I have to study Mvc4 api. Thanks so much for your contributions